# Can an American Bulldog tolerate Wisconsin temperatures?

Tags: dogs, health, temperature

My American Bulldog spends the night indoors (not heated) but then is outside for 12 hours every day.  Will my dog be okay during winter? If not, what precautions should I take?

Comment: I've edited your question to fit our format, please take a look and edit it further if you wish.

Comment: Might find this useful: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/when-does-a-dog-need-to-wear-a-jacket-or-sweater

Comment: Where in Wisconsin? Also, are you keeping the dog outside for 12 hours/day when the temperatures are -40F? This seems like animal abuse.